# IIS. Unable to create a virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-8.1

I'm using VS 2012 on Windows 8.1. I did everything as was said in this tutorial: [How to connect to a local web service from the Windows Phone 8 Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx). But on the step where I should disable "Use IIS Express" and put url with my IP: `http://10.17.192.179/WebServiceForTesting` I'm getting an error: **Unable to create a virtual directory**. I edited the .csproj file in the project like this: `<IISUrl>http://localhost/WebServiceForTesting</IISUrl>` 
I've also tried to execute this line in the VS cmd: `aspnet_regiis -r`

I struggled with it the whole day, but couldn't find any solution. Is there any other solution I might try to get it work?

**EDIT:** I added a virtual directory in the IIS Manager with the same physical path where my website is located and tried to create a virtual directory in the VS again. But it didn't help.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't create the Virtual Directory in IIS Manager?

Comment: What physical path should I type there? Could you tell me how will it look like?

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as an Administrator? Do you have IIS installed?

Comment: What is 10.17.192.179, is it your development box, a local-area-network server, an internet server?  When you disable IIS Express, you are implicitly telling visual studio to use the full featured IIS.  The full featured IIS needs to be setup properly in order for visual studio to map the site/application to your project.

Comment: Yes, I'm running VS as an Administrator and have IIS installed.

Comment: I've got that IP (10.17.192.179) by running ipconfig in the command line. Is there any tutorial where I can find how to disable IIS Express and properly setup full featured IIS?